# Avoid runtime overflow of pixels in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget

I am using flutter for developing a hybrid application for both iOS and android. I am trying to prepare responsive page, and I am able to use the width and height properties of Media query. The problem begins when I try to get my application from full screen to split screen, there it is not adapting with the screen size. I want to know if is there any widget which could be used to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You could use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and customise of 3 (small, medium, large) sizes (heights) if you want in split screen

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the **Parent Widget** of class in `SingleChildScrollView`

```
   SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Scaffold(
                 .
                 .
                 .
       )
    )
```